# Spark Sql is throwing PermGen Space Error

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, apache-spark-sql, permgen

I have configured 3 Node Spark Cluster. And started Spark Thrift Service using `start-thriftserver.sh` script with some custom properties. And also added `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=256m` property in each `spark-default.sh` file of the Cluster.

Using the Hive JDBC driver, I am able to connect with spark-sql, have tried some queries on it.

But after some time it's throwing `PermGen Space` error. And after restarting thrift service so many times it is throwing same error.

[image]

Comment: How this question is duplicate? I already tried with large heap space `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=256m`. And if is it then write the solution that will resolve my problem.

Comment: I am not able to understand. Without any proper reason,  why people are downvoteing the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

I went through the application log, permgen error occurs by the Spark driver so Instead of `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` option, I added `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=256m` properties with `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` option.